# How can I create a dictionary from a list of k:v tuples returned from a SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, sqlite

My SQL (sqlite3) query is along the lines of this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM mytable;
```

This returns a ton of rows.  I would like to create a dictionary from these results, where I can lookup the name given an id.

Other answers I've found seem to create dictionaries based on SQL results, but they use the column label as the key -- I have no interest in that.

Example table:

```
id    | name
------+--------
foo   | bar
baz   | foobar
```

Desired dict:

```
{
    'foo': 'bar',
    'baz': 'foobar'
}
```

Comment: Give a [mcve] please.

Comment: @JulienBernu done.

Comment: Use a [```dictionary comprehension```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=displays#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result returned from cursor is a list of 2-elements tuples so you can just convert that to a dictionary as the first item of each tuple is a unique value:

```
result = dict(cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM mytable"))
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work.  I get this error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: Nope, the query I listed is verbatim the same query (with a different table name, but that's it).

Comment: How does the query result look like?

Comment: It seems to be returning a list of dicts.  So I think the error is related to the fact that there's only one element (a dict) that's returned.

Comment: Please post your code fetching the results from db. You are clearly doing something different than what you described in the question.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I was using a row_factory (provided from another answer) that was messing with the output.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the rows (the [result cursor is iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3)), [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) the key and value, then assemble the result using a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
desired_dict = {k:v for k, v in c.execute('SELECT id, name FROM MyTable')}
```

I like using dict comprehensions because I can do additional processing to the results before adding to the dictionary (for example changing case, converting to decimal or datetime, etc).

That said, if you want to go directly to the dict, *ozgur* has the shorter, faster way which is to call [*dict()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) directly:

```
desired_dict = dict(c.execute('SELECT id, name FROM MyTable'))
```

Here's an actual sample session demonstrating the process start to finish:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> c = sqlite3.connect('tmp.db')
>>> c.execute('CREATE TABLE MyTable (id text, name text)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106227f80>
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('abc', 'Alpha')")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106283810>
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('def', 'Beta')")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106227f80>
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('ghi', 'Gamma')")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106283810>
>>> c.commit()
>>> c.close()
>>> 
>>> c = sqlite3.connect('tmp.db')
>>> {k:v for k, v in c.execute('SELECT id, name FROM MyTable')}
{'ghi': 'Gamma', 'def': 'Beta', 'abc': 'Alpha'}
```

Comment: Using your original suggestion, I get this error: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @ComtriS I added an actual session to demonstrate all the steps start to finish.  How that helps you work out the kinks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you get your sql query result in Python, something like

`db_conn = sqlite3.connect('text.db')
cur = db_conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''select id, name from mytable''')`

Then you can get all the query results in the return of `cur.fetchall()`.
The result will be a list of tuples, each tuple will be like (*id*,*name*).

Knowing this, then it is a piece of cake to transform it into an dictionary,just:

`mydict = {}
for item in cur.fetchall():
    mydict[item[0]] = item[1]`